# How to select multiple events with keyboard in Apple Calendar?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, automator, calendar.app

In Apple Calendar, `Shift/Cmd + Click` can select multiple calendar events with a mouse.

How can I select multiple events with only the keyboard?

[Apple's "Keyboard shortcuts in Calendar on Mac"](https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/keyboard-shortcuts-ical002/mac) doesn't seem to list any way to do this.

I'm interested in *alternative solutions, hacks, & additional software* to accomplish this via ***any means possible*** because I use Calendar very, very often. I don't know much about these topics, but they seem potentially useful:

- Mac "Accessibility" settings (?)
- AppleScripts (?)
- Automator (?)
- Alfred (?)
- BetterTouchTool (?)
- Karabiner (?)
- System-wide macros (?)
- Programmable keyboard (?)
- Apple "Shortcuts" app (?)